# Disable legend click on NVD3 multichart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I have a nvd3 multichart. two line chart and I want to disable legend click. 
I am using d3 version 3.5.5 and nvd3 version 1.7.1

live code sample [jsfiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/khanSharp/yLsktkg2/2/)

I tried the following according to [github answer](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues/65)

```
chart.legend.disptach.on('legendClick', function() { 
    return; //do nothing
});
```

but it doesn't work for my current version of nvd3.
Do you have any clue how this might work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I never used nvd3.js and I'm not familiar with the library, but if it's good enough to you this is a solution using D3:

```
d3.selectAll(".nv-series").style("cursor", "default").on("click", null);
```

Here is your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/91Lpzu8u/

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the legend click event by using the below code line:

```
chart.legend.updateState(false);
```

On hover over the legend, you would still get the hand-cursor but that can be fixed by CSS.

```
.nvd3 .nv-legend .nv-series {    
    cursor: default !important;
}
```